# Spring test mockmvc actual:500 expected:200

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, junit, mocking

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong testing wise, I simply can't make a test work despite following tutorial and SO topic.

Here is my code that gives me a expected 200 recieved:500, I would appreciate if someone could point me to a good ressource for test since I can't find one that give working example, or tell me which basic principle I'm not grasping that I should focus on.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
@WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @MockBean
    private User user;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new UserController()).build();  //Construct MockMVC
    }


    @Test
    public void whenValidInput_thenReturns200() throws Exception {
        Cart cart = Cart.builder().build();
        Date birthdate = new Date(1978-06-06);
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        User user = new User(1231231231231L, "Denis", "Pierre", "pierre@hotmail.com", "pass", "adresse", birthdate, cart);
        String json = ow.writeValueAsString(user);
      
        when(
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/users/register/", user)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()));

    }

}
```

Here is the MovieController

```
  @PostMapping("/users/register")
    public ResponseEntity<User> registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        try {
            Optional<User> userData = userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
            if (userData.isPresent()) {
                // existing email, cannot register
                return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
            } else {
                userService.saveUser(user);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

And here is the exact error message I get:

```
11:51:58.389 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Nothing to write: null body
11:51:58.392 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to add `/api/users/register/` code as it's failing in execution.

Comment: First there should be some error log messages on your log file or console. Second, you shouldn't need to setup mockMvc if you have "@AutoConfigureMockMvc" annotation. And finally, it is really hard to make any comment without knowing at least the signature of the controller function.

Comment: You're mixing up quite some Spring Boot test slice annotations. I'd suggest to first take a look at this [Spring Boot test slice overview](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-test-slices-overview-and-usage/), then this article on [@MockBean vs. @Mock](https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/) and then decide what test you want to write. Either go with a integration test and `@SpringBootTest` (and optionally `MockMvc`) or a sliced test using `@WebMvcTest`

Comment: @Kernal I added the controller code and the error message I'm getting in the OP.